# Vue.js on focus textbox on load

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

How to focus on load using VueJS?

If using jquery, all i should do is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#username').focus();
});
```

Is there a vue-way or not?

Comment: Here you go: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html

Comment: @sobolevn thanks :3

Comment: Nice to know that it's right in the docs, thanks @sobolevn. (Depending on your use-case, you could also use the `autofocus` html attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms_in_HTML#The_autofocus_attribute)

Comment: too bad in my case autofocus didn't work T_T)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can create a custom directive for that:

```
// Register a global custom directive called v-focus
Vue.directive('focus', {
  // When the bound element is inserted into the DOM...
  inserted: function (el) {
    // Focus the element
    el.focus()
  }
})
```

And then use it like this:

```
<input v-focus>
```

Full example from the docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html

Directive docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-directive